# Our Google plus communities posts are keep being removed

Tags: google-plus

From some reason our Google plus communities posts are keep being removed without any indication in our G+ home page.

In the past, when our post was removed there was a strike line on the post title in our home page like this example:

[image]

Today we do not see this indication, while our post is dropped.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, from some reason the question part was dropped. I updated the post. The addition is: Today we do not see this indication, while our post is dropped. Does anyone know why?